# How does one mention “first class honors” and GPA correctly on a résumé?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, capitalization

On my résumé, I have the following:

> -----Bachelor of ABC, Institute of XYZ, Country-----
>
> > "first class honors" and GPA

I can't construct this line in a way that sounds completely correct. Which of the following is the right way?

1. Graduated *with* First Class Honors *and* a GPA of X.
2. Graduated First Class Honors *with* a GPA of X.
3. Graduated *with* First Class Honors *with* a GPA of X.
4. ...

Also, should it be capitalized *first-class*, *First-class*, or *First Class*?

Comment: I guess this is for the US market? The UK would be very different.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yeah. How would it be in the UK though?

Comment: In a CV/resume, something like "University of Surrey, UK: BSc(Hons) Civil Engineering, 1987." The date, degree and institution might appear in a different order depending on style within the CV. Definitely no mention of honours grade or GPA, though.

Comment: Maybe transform it to latin to make something like _Magna cum laude (GPA X)_

Comment: @Vilmar Not an option. The transcript must say the same.

Comment: @DarkCthulhu In that case I'd stick with first option.

Comment: This seems like a question for careers.SE

Comment: I'm just throwing this out as a reality check...there is likely not a single correct answer nor an informed enough audience to know what that is.  There's an interesting article in the NYTimes (http://www.nytimes.com/2009/05/15/opinion/15Francese.html?_r=0) discussing among other things how a Harvard diploma was rejected in a job application because Harvard's diplomas are in Latin calligraphy and it was "returned as foreign and illegible" by the prospective employer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first suggestion, Graduated with First Class Honors and a GPA of X, not only seems legit (as another user said); it is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few different ways to format education on a resume, and in part it depends on how much you have or want to list.

---

Honors can also be listed as:

- Cum Laude: with honor
- Magna Cum Laude: with great honor
- Summa Cum Laude: with highest honor

---

**1**

University -- Campus, City
Degree name (cum laude), month year -- other awards, GPA: x.x <sub>1.</sub>

---

**2**

List the honors separately:

HONORS

List item 1  years
List item 2  years <sub>2.</sub>

---

**3**

Bachelor of XX, Major       month year
Minor: minor
University, campus, city
GPA x.x,  Cum Laude Honors

---

**4**

The Harvard Law School Advises:

> You should include two separate subsections for each educational degree: "Honors" and "Activities."  <sub>3.</sub>

**UNIVERSITY**
 Degree XX with  Honors in XYZ and ZYX, month year
Honours:   details here

Activities:  details here

---

References:

1. [Put Your Education to Work on Your Resume](http://career-advice.monster.com/resumes-cover-letters/resume-writing-tips/put-your-education-to-work/article.aspx)
   By Kim Isaacs, Monster Resume Expert
2. [Format: Résumé Honors / Awards](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~jlarsen/rex2/honors.html)
3. [Resume Layout Guidance](http://www.law.harvard.edu/current/careers/opia/toolkit/resumes/resume-layout.html)
   Harvard Law School

Comment: Awarded bounty for the amazing set of links and references. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about this, a nice surprise to wake up to. And good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Your first construction seems legit. You can add: Graduated with.....and an overall GPA of X.

You might also put it like this:

Awarded First-class Honours(or Honors) for an overall GPA of X.

Cheers

Edit: and its First-class(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Class_Honours#First-class_honours)